# jmeter illegal character found in host: &apos;/&apos;

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm trying to run jmeter to launch a load test.

One thing that I found strange is that I can run the following jmeter command in macOS without any problem.

```
PROTOCOL=https
DOMAIN=mywebsite.com/API
PORT=443
LOOP=1
THREADS=1

/var/jenkins_home/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/jmeter \
  -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml \
  -Jprotocol=${PROTOCOL} \
  -Jdomain=${DOMAIN} \
  -Jport=${PORT} \
  -Jloop=${LOOP} \
  -Jthreads=${THREADS} \
  -n -t mywebsite.jmx \
  -l jmeter.jtl \
  -j mywebsite.log
```

But when I run the above command a linux machine, I got the error saying.

```
<httpSample t="0" it="0" lt="0" ct="0" ts="0" s="false" lb="" rc="Non HTTP response code: java.net.MalformedURLException" rm="Non HTTP response message: Illegal character found in host: &apos;/&apos;" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="822" sby="0" ng="1" na="1">
  <null/>
</httpSample>
```

And 100% of the jmeter requests failed.

This error message is found in `jmeter.jtl` result file.

It looks like that jmeter doesn't allow `/` in its domain in the linux environment. My domain `mywebsite.com/API` contains a `/` symbol.

The java version on my macOS is

```
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

and the java version on my linux machine is

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

The jmeter on both of the systems is 5.1.1.

Does anyone know what goes wrong in my linux environment?

Comment: `mywebsite.com/API` is not a valid domain name. Use something else.

Comment: But why can I use it in macOS?

Comment: @Brian Java's magical virtual machine

Comment: `-Jdomain=${DOMAIN} -Jpath=${PATH}` (mywebsite.com and /API) with a truncated DOMAIN would seem the regular thing to try.

Comment: @Brian not sure. My guess is that macOS will only use `mywebsite.com`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have `/` character as a part of server DNS hostname.

As per [hostname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hostname.7.html) documentation:

> Each element of the hostname must be from 1 to 63 characters long and
>          the entire hostname, including the dots, can be at most 253
>          characters long.  Valid characters for hostnames are ASCII(7) letters
>          from a to z, the digits from 0 to 9, and the hyphen (-).  A hostname
>          may not start with a hyphen.

So you either need to split your `DOMAIN` property into:

```
HOSTNAME=mywebsite.com
PATH=/API
```

and use the properties in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults/)) like:

[image]

or alternatively leave "Server Name or IP" field blank and move your `DOMAIN` property to "Path" field like:

[image]

But in this case the configuration elements like [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) which rely on the hostname might not work properly